# Is it possible to update the textfield in Material design date picker?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, android-datepicker

is it possible to add an outline and hide the mm/dd/yyyy text in material design date picker :
https://material.io/components/date-pickers#anatomy

I am trying to make it such that the outline of textfield should be customizable.
Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by the `MM/DD/YYYY` text as Date picker itself is a dialog?

Comment: i updated the screenshot in my question. i want to hide the mm/dd/yyyy that shows up on material deisng datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the style of the TextField using:

```
    MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
        .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_DatePicker)
        .build()
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.DatePicker" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <!-- Customize text field of the text input mode. -->
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response :) is this design possible? https://i.postimg.cc/DyVLH79m/Screen-Shot-2021-06-11-at-11-59-35-AM.png with material date picker

Comment: @AngelaHeely you can only customize the style, otherwise you can add in your project an own custom [mtrl_picker_text_input_date.xml](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/res/layout/mtrl_picker_text_input_date.xml) layout.

Comment: so I can't remove the "date" part from your screenshot to make it a standalone textfield like in my design? Also, is it not possible to place mm/dd/yyyy above the textfield?

Comment: can I remove the mm/dd/yyyy hint? is that something that will be possible in an inactive state before the user even taps on the textbox.

Comment: @AngelaHeely The only way to achieve it is to create a custom mtrl_picker_text_input_date.xml layout as describe in the previous comment.

Comment: Is it possible to add input masking to this textfield?

Comment: @AngelaHeely No it is not supported.